# Angular Custom Decorator - using service

Tags: angular, typescript, service, decorator

I'm interested to create a custom auth decorator, something like @Auth().

The question is what is the right way to implement that.

Is there any way to use service inside of the decorator?
Is there any way to access Component data members inside of decorator? (target object...)

Comment: And the biggest question is, whether that is the right pattern to implement auth anyway

Comment: Your question is way to broad to be answered. But for the parts that can : yes, you can use an instance of a service inside of a decorator, but the service must be globally registered (not coming from your component's injector), and no, you can't access component data inside of a decorator (a decorator is applied to the class itself, not an instance of the class)